# Adding text via Powershell to XML file without element tags

Tags: xml, powershell

I'm trying to add a line of text to my XML document via Powershell for my phonebook generator that allows LDAP lookup queries for our numbers

```
"(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(|(cn=%)(sn=%)))(|(telephoneNumber=%)(mobile=%)(ipPhone=%))7"
```

I had a long google online and can't seem to find a way to add this into the XML without placing it within an element/node.

Is there a way to just simply append it to the XML without having it being attached to a node?

Answer (score 1):

Everything in a **valid** XML document is a node, even the text within elements are nodes. If you just append a string to an XML document, it no longer becomes XML. At that point it's just a text file. But, if you truly want to, treat your XML document like a regular text file with `Out-File`

```
$LDAP = "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(|(cn=%)(sn=%)))(|(telephoneNumber=%)(mobile=%)(ipPhone=%))7"
$LDAP | Out-File -FilePath yourxmldoc.xml -Append
```